# Will I be able to transform back from a werewolf to a human or do I have to wait?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

In Skyrim will I be able to transform from a werewolf to a human whenever I want or do I have to wait a specific time? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The werewolf transformation has a timer attached to it. When you transform you need to wait until the timer expires, before you turn back.

Once transformed, the Dragonborn remains a werewolf for 2.5 minutes of real time. It is possible to extend this time by approaching a corpse and feeding on it by activating it as if looting it. This restores 50 points of Health and gives an additional 30 seconds of time as a werewolf.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Additionally, in [tag:skyrim-dawnguard] feeding an a corpse builds credit towards your next Werewolf Perk.